# Ability to add link to Dropbox folder in Trello cards

Tags: dropbox, links, trello-cards

I wish I was able to add link to a Dropbox folder, not only Dropbox file.
Links to folders are already implemented in Dropbox. How can I use such ability in Trello cards?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but linking to a folder works for me.

1. Go to dropbox.com
2. Click "Share" on the folder you want to share.
3. Click "Send link."
4. Copy the link.
5. Open Trello.
6. Open the card you want to link the Dropbox folder to.
7. Click "Attachment"
8. Paste the link into the "Attach a Link" box (**NOT** the "Dropbox" menu item).

It should add a link to the card that, when clicked, opens up the folder you shared in Dropbox.

Comment: Gah...didn't see the date on this was 2013. Well, this might have been a new implementation since then, but for those coming after this is how you share a link to a Dropbox folder. =D